# Hopf bifurcation - System Transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following system:

$$\dot u=\mu u-v+u^2-v^2-u(u+v)^2 \\
\dot v=u+\mu v-uv-v(u^2-uv+v^2)$$

My lecture notes about Dynamical Systems says that this system can be transformed into

$$\dot x=\mu x-y-x(x^2+y^2)+O(\epsilon^4)\\
\dot y=x+\mu y-y(x^2+y^2)+O(\epsilon^4)$$

by the non-linear transformation $u=x+x y, v=y$ with $u,v=O(\epsilon)$ and $\mu=O(\epsilon ^2)$

I do not see how to derive the second system, may you can help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to begin with the equation for $\dot{v}$ - substitute in and you see

$$\begin{align}
\dot{y}
& = x + xy + \mu y - (x+xy)y - y(x^2 + 2x^2y + x^2y^2 - xy - xy^2 + y^2) \\
& = x + \mu y - y(x^2 + y^2) + O(\epsilon^4)
\end{align}$$

where $O(\epsilon^4)$ subsumes all terms that are at least fourth order in $x$ or $y$. Now you can do the same for the equation involving $\dot{u}$. This is more complicated, as the lhs expands to

$$\dot{u} = \dot{x} + \dot{x}y + x\dot{y} = \dots$$

so you will need to substitute in from your equation for $\dot{y}$. Then again, simply cancel the higher-order terms (each $x$ and $y$ counts for one power of $\epsilon$ and the $\mu$ counts for $\epsilon^2$) and see what you are left with.

Comment: For the second one I get $u'=x'+x'y+x^2+\mu xy-xy(x^2+y^2)+xO(\epsilon ^4)$, but how to simplify it to get something like $x'=...$